# How does setxattr in memory.py change anything?

Tags: python, fuse

I'm using memory.py from fusepy (http://code.google.com/p/fusepy/source/browse/trunk/memory.py) for a programming assignment.

How does setxattr (line 87) actually accomplish anything? self.files isn't modified in any way and attrs is destroyed when the function exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def setxattr(self, path, name, value, options, position=0):
    # Ignore options
    attrs = self.files[path].setdefault('attrs', {})
    attrs[name] = value
```

The side-effect is achieved by [`setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), which creates a new item in `self.files[path]` (unless `attrs` already exists as a key in it), and returns a *reference* to the value.

Next, that reference is modified, by assigning to its key `name`, the value `value`.  By that operation too, `self.files` is modified.

Comment: Where can I see what setdefault does? I knew it could be done is attrs pointed to a piece of self.files, but I think I read python doesn't really do pointers. My background is much stronger in C++, python is totally new to me.

Comment: if you're used to C++, think about it this way: *everything is a pointer* in python